# Cannot find module '@angular-devkit.../utils' when trying to run ionic on android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I try and run `ionic cordova run android --device` in order to run my ionic app off of my phone I recieve this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TnwF.png).

`Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils`

However, `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is installed, as it's there in my `package.json`. I've already tried `npm install` after deleting it but no luck.

My ionic is version ~5.5.2

And my @angular-devkit/build-angular is version ~0.1100.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change package.json file
   @angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0"
2. rm -rf node_module
3. run npm i

I solved perfectly :).

Comment: ~0.1002.0 is also working. Seems like Ionic depends on a package, which got removed from the latest @angular-devkit/build-angular